# A Python program to print the instance attribute

Tags: python

Here inside the class `apsara`, inside the instance method `write`, I defined the object `woodpen` assigned to `1`. As of now `woodpen` is not an object of `apsara`, now how the code doesn't raise attribute error, but shows the answer `10` and `10`.

```
class apsara:
    def write(self):
        woodpen = 1
        print(self.height)

woodpen = apsara()
tippen = apsara()

woodpen.height = 10
woodpen.write()
print(woodpen.height)
```

I was expecting an attribute error of `int object has no attribute height` but it shows

```
10
10
```

Comment: `woodpen.height = 10` adds a `height` attribute to `woodpen`.

Comment: And `woodpen = 1` is inside a method so creates a new _local_ variable, it doesn't magically override the `woodpen` _outside_ the method.

Comment: correct!.... the print statement outside should print 10. But the print statement inside the method also prints 10. How is that possible.

Comment: The print statement inside the method simply ignores the local variable that the method creates. The line `woodpen = 1` has no effect. It doesn't set `self` to 1 in the case that you call the method on an object named `woodpen`.

Comment: How is that possible. Why is it neglected. Kindly explain like u explain to a beginner .
and additionally, if I print(woodpen.height) replacing the print(self.height) now it shows attribute error. 
Is it a compiler error ?
eventhough self is not assigned to 1, but the woodpen is not even an object now , right?
then how height can still be the attribute of woodpen

Comment: Your real question seems to be about how scope works in Python. Too much to cover in a comment. Any good book or tutorial should have a section on variable scope.

Comment: I know how local and global variables work actually. But it seems like I miss something. What should I search in youtube. or could you refer me some videos or any blog posts. thank you

Comment: @JohnColeman. Is it really too much? `woodpen` only exists in the method `.write()`, until global variable of the same name is assigned an instance of aspara (should be Aspara with capital A), class/object does not have attribute `height`  before it is created outside the class definition, so it would give attribute error if printed before `woodpen.height = 10` What's too much?

Comment: what I know is,computer take the last attribute value if duplicates exist.So here first computer reads woodpen=apsara(),then when the method write() is called,the computer enters into the function block of write(), where there computer reads woodpen =1. So now woodpen is not an object inside the function block(since it is a local variable). then the self parameter will fetch the woodpen as argument and places in self.height as woodpen.height.Already computer read that woodpen is not an object,so in either ways of printing(self.height) or print(woodpen.height),attribute error should occur right

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys A full exposition of scope is too much for a comment, though you show how it is possible to succinctly  explain what the specific issue is here in a single comment.

Comment: can you both pls not fight, and help me instead. So that I can do well my test tomorrow. pls

@JohnColeman

Comment: I don't think it's fighting. It is difficult to write a full answer and what's even worse - it might be pointless. I think many people will hesitate to write an answer since this is very well covered by many tutorials online. It might be best and easiest to follow John's advice and look for a tutorial on scope. First Google or YouTube result for "python scope" should help.

Comment: In the body of the method the local variable `woodpen` refers to 1, which of course has no attribute `height`. On the other hand, `self` refers to the object that you call the method on, which could also be called `woodpen` in the calling code - the method code doesn't care. The local variable `woodpen` doesn't refer to the object by the same name.

Comment: ok... I'll search it. Thank you guys.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> class apsara:
...     def write(self):
...         woodpen = 1
...         print(self.height)
...
>>> woodpen = apsara()
>>> tippen = apsara()
>>>
>>> woodpen.height = 10
>>> woodpen.write()
10
>>> print(woodpen.height)
10
>>> woodpen.woodpen
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'apsara' object has no attribute 'woodpen'
```